# How do i connect to a sock4 client's network byte address?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to make a socks 4 proxy server with boost-asio. How can i connect to the site specified by the client if its in network byte order? Can you please provide examples. I'm using a linux so no winsock.

sock4request is what the server receive from the client.

```
            const boost::array<unsigned char,4> addr={sock4request[5],sock4request[6],sock4request[7],sock4request[8]}; //Network byte address
            unsigned char port[]={sock4request[3],sock4request[4]};
            boost::asio::ip::address_v4 addrip(addr);
            unsigned short portint=lexical_cast<unsigned short>(port);
            tcp::endpoint addrinfo(addrip,portint);
            tcp::socket finalsocket(io_service);
            boost::asio::connect(finalsocket,endpoint_iterator);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've already tried? Maybe include some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built-in linux functions like htons, ntohs..
Please review this page:

http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use it please? I don't think I'm using it correctly. http://pastebin.com/tdEqbxE9